# Giving your own ids to Core Data objects

Tags: core-data

I have some points on a map with associated informations contained by Core Data, to link the points on the map with the associated info, I would like to have an ID for each point, so in my entity, I would need some ID property, I have read that Core Data has it's own IDs for every managed object but I'm wondering wether or not it would be a good approach for me to directly use them or if I should create my own ID system ?

If you think I should create my OWN ID system, how would I do that ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

CoreData is not an relational database and you should avoid thinking about own ID’s. You may need them only for syncing purposes with external databases. For more precise answer, you should write how your model looks.

[edited after comment]
I don't see that you need any relations. Let's sat you have `MapPoint` entity with `lat`, and `long` properties. If there is only one user note, you just add another property to it like notes. If you have many informations (many records) stored with one `MapPoint` you need to add `Notes` entity with properties `note` and `mappoint` and make a relation between them. When you insert new `Notes` object into CoreData you set mappoint property to already existing `MapPoint` object (fetched after user tap).

Comment: Actually, the user can add it's own points to a map, every time the user adds a point, I save it in Core Data in an entity that has longitude, latitude and other properties. When the app is launched again, I load all of the saved entities and display them on the map, but what I want is, when the user taps on a point of the map, to display more informations about it, and since these informations are stored in Core Data, I would need to have a link between the points of the map and the objects stored in core data. I don't know at all what's the best approach...